# Delete activerecord row which is older than the newest record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wasn't running validations, and therefore I have duplicates in my db. Now I need to delete the record which is older than the latest record. What's the best way to do this in Ruby?

I do this to find the dups from just one shop:

```
customers = Shop.find(105).customers
emails = customers.pluck(:shop_id, :id, :customer_id, :email, :created_at, :credit_amount )
gemails = emails.group_by{ |shop_id, id, customer_id, email, created_at, credit_amount_to_f| customer_id }
gemails.delete_if{ |_, v| v.compact.size <= 1 }
```

`gemails` returns the dups with the `customer_id` as the key.

I can then find the most recent record for the first duplicate like this:

```
Customer.where(customer_id: gemails.keys[0]).order("updated_at").last
```

How do I get rid of all the records that share the `customer_id` that aren't the last one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you can find the id of the order you do not want to delete (the most recent) - this is similar to what you already have but it's more efficient to use `:desc` to order the records in a way that the newest (the highest date) is first, that way you can use `limit(1)` and `.first`:

```
customer_id = gemails.keys[0]
first_order_id = Customer.where(customer_id: customer_id).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(1).first.id
```

then you can delete all the customer's orders which don't share the same order id:

```
Customer.where(customer_id: customer_id).where.not(id: first_order_id).delete_all
```

You should make a copy of your data before doing this stuff - I would hate for any mistake I made to cause you to lose data.

Also this is the sort of thing which would be maybe useful for testing or one-time data cleanup, but you should be using validations in your models to prevent the data from reaching this state in the first place.